# When should I use the custom moderator flag for off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, declined-flags

I've looked over a couple dozen meta posts and none seems to specifically answer my question.

Recently, I raised a flag on a question, [Why can't we build in python a JavaScript-like import system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101617/why-cant-we-build-in-python-a-javascript-like-import-system) (removed). The question was essentially asking "Why does Python have such a terrible import system? Using [coding method], we could have the same import system as JavaScript!"

I felt the post was off-topic, since, per the [on-topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the question was not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development." Additionally, as per the [don't-ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), this was an instance of "your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”." While I understand that sometimes [subjective questions are allowed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), this doesn't seem like an answerable question. As noted in the blog post,

> Thus, **questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates, opinions — should be closed as subjective**.

And nobody can really answer why a JS-like import system has not been created for Python. It just hasn't been created. If someone would like to make it then they can, but there is no *reason* why it can't be done.

However, when I went to flag the question, none of the available options seemed to fit:

[image: Off-Topic Flags]

So I used a custom flag:

> Should be closed because it's off-topic, but doesn't seem to fit any of the off-topic reasons given above. Complaining about the woes of Python is not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" as required by the Asking guidelines. – [Michael Kolber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555108/michael-kolber) 20 hours ago   *declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)*

However, none of the standard flags seemed to fit:

- The question is not about **general computing hardware and software**, but rather about the intricacies of Python
- It does not relate to **server- or networking-related** topics
- It is not asking for a **recommendation**
- It is not seeking **debugging help** or trying to **fix an error**
- It is not **blatantly off-topic**, as it very-much has to do with programming, it's just not an answerable question
- There wasn't really a good option of an SE site to migrate the post to

In fact, I specifically mentioned in the flag my reason for not using a standard flag. And, since the mod did not mention anything about the flag being incorrect, I would assume that the post was indeed off-topic.

**So which flag should I have used? In the future, how can I know which standard flag to raise when none seem to fit?**

Comment: While you're still using flags and not close votes, what you flag as isn't as important. Us 3k users have access to a "none of the above"-option (https://i.imgur.com/NRqyXS1.png - available on all sites, not just meta) for when the standard flags don't suffice. That being said, the question is too broad. if you edit out the rant (in your head or actually doing it, but I wouldn't bother for that question), you'll see it's a question, but it's far too broad. Flagging it as too broad (flagging -> closing -> too broad) would be one appropriate way in this case. (that being said, multiple can apply

Comment: I would have closed it as being `primarily opinion based` not off topic.

Comment: @Zoe I was not aware of that, thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Dave I feel very stupid, I fully agree with you and did not even see that flag. I guess I was too focused on the "off-topic" aspect (although moderator feedback on which specific flag to raise would have been nice).

Comment: Frankly, I'm not a fan of the idea that "standard flags" should be preferred. If the standard flags don't seem to fit a situation, I would much rather see a clear, detailed explanation of why you are flagging, just as you provided.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on the title alone:

> Why can't we build in python a JavaScript-like import system?

Close voting as Primarily Opinion Based would have been fine, as would have been Too broad.

Don't use custom flags on posts where the moderator would need to be a subject matter expert to judge the validity of your flag. If you do, a good explanation is needed. Yours looked fine but it still is an hit and miss game.

Only use moderator flags to moderate a post in ways the community is unable to do. If you can't come up with a good close reason, maybe it shouldn't be closed or for sure someone else from the community can pick the right reason.

If you need an extra pair of eyes on a post and a moderation advice, feel free to hop in the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where the regulars are happy to help out. Before joining do read the awesome page turner we created called the [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq).

Comment: Thanks for providing the rationale. However, `Don't use custom flags on posts where the moderator would need to be a subject matter expert to judge the validity of your flag.` -- can you please explain this? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @MichaelKolber supose you custom flag a question about [tag:Haskell] to be closed and [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=tags) is the moderator who handles the flag. What do you think will happen? Now think about a question you flagged is about Python and Martijn will run across your flag. See the difference? There are only 26 mods and over 40.000 tags ...

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something in my understanding of flag handling. Are standard flags handled differently than custom flags (other than being placed into a high-priority queue). And I appreciate you taking the time to explain.

Comment: @MichaelKolber Yes, custom flags go only to the moderator queue where only one of the 26 diamond moderators will handle your flag. All other flags go to the review queue where users with review privileges wil judge them. (basically users with 500 reputation or more)

Comment: Understood, unlike standard flags which can be handled by badged users.